# Hash table problem for education perposes

Tags: python, hashtable

The problem is this:
It is required to create and use the **hash table structure** in a problem
large number of keys.

Here are the steps:

Creating one million (1,000,000) visits to a department store
and Credit Card Payment.

From the very large number of different cards, a relatively small subset is created
as follows. Credit cards for visits will have
sixteen (16) specific fixed digits eg 1234567890123456,
but in four (4) of the sixteen (16) random positions they will also have
four characters: X, Y, Z, W in random order.
eg 12Y45W789012Z4X6
In the other places the prices are the initial ones.

I have written the codes. Is is supposed to run super fast but it runs super slowly and I don't know why... Currently, I am running my code for 10,000 cards. Could you help me? Please excuse my poor english...

The code is bellow:

```
import string
import random
import time

random.seed(1059442)
global max_load_factor

max_load_factor = 0.6

def printGreaterThan2(num):
while True:
    if num % 2 == 1:
        isPrime = True

        for x in range(3,int(num**0.5),2):
            if num % x == 0:
                isPrime = False
                break
        if isPrime:
            return num
    num += 1

N = printGreaterThan2(1000)


arr = [ [] for _ in range(N)]
arr = [ None for _ in range(N)]



def CreatNewItem():
letters = "WXZY"
days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed" , "Thu" , "Fri", "Sat"]
s = ''
count = 0
num = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6']
list_a = []

while(count!=4):
    a = random.randint(0,15)
    b = random.choice(letters)
    if b not in num and a not in list_a:
        num[a] = b
        count = count + 1
        list_a.append(a)

s = ''.join(num)

d = random.randint(0,5)
day = days[d]
money = random.randint(10,100)
a = [s,day,money]

return a



def hash(key, tablesize):
    sum = 0
    for pos in range(len(key)):
        sum = sum + ord(key[pos])
    hash = sum % tablesize
    return hash

#--------------------------------------
def rehash(oldhash , tablesize):
    rehash = ( oldhash + 1 ) % tablesize
    return rehash
#--------------------------------------
def put2 (arr,a,N,lenght,collitions):

    if float(lenght)/float(N) >= max_load_factor:
        (arr,N,collitions) = Resize(arr,N,lenght,collitions)


    key = a[0]
    i  = hash(key,N)
    j =0 

    while (True):

        if arr[i] is None:
            arr[i] = a
            lenght = lenght + 1
            break

        elif arr[i][0] == key:
            arr[i][2] = arr[i][2] + a[2]
            arr[i][1] = arr[i][1] + a[1]
            break

        else:
            if j == 0 :
                collitions = collitions +1 
                j = 1
            i = rehash(i,N)

    return (lenght,N,arr,collitions ) 





#----------------------------------------


def Resize(arr,N,lenght,collitions):
    print("resize")
    N = printGreaterThan2(2*N)
    collitions = 0

    arr2 = [ [] for _ in range(N)]
    arr2 = [ None for _ in range(N)]

    for p in arr:
        if p is not None:
            (lenght,N,arr2,collitions)=put2(arr2,p,N,lenght,collitions)

    return (arr2,N,collitions)


#-----------------------------------------    
l = 0
cards = []
collitions = 0



t0 = time.time()
i=0

while i!=10000:
    b = CreatNewItem()

    (l,N,arr,collitions) = put2(arr,b,N,l,collitions)

    i=i+1


t1 = time.time() - t0
print('\ntime is {:0.20f}'.format(t1))
```